# Generalization of Sylow's third theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Suppose $p^b||G|$, $0\le a\le b$. $H\le G$ is a subgroup of order $p^a$. Show that the number of subgroups of $G$ containing $H$ and of order $p^b$ is congruent to $1$ mod $p$.

By Wielandt's proof of Sylow's theorem, I can see the proposition is true for $H=1$. To prove the general result, maybe we can use induction on $a$ or $b-a$, or modify Wielandt's proof cleverly, but I cannot proceed.

I considered the set $S=\{K\le G:|K|=p^b\text{ and }H\le K\}$, but I could not find an appropriate group action.

[Here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/321912135058.pdf.bannered.pdf) is a proof of the proposition using Möbius inversion. I want to know a proof using basic group theory.

Any hints are appreciated.